# Can I still get 'Vinayaka Vijayam' by LIFCO somewhere in TamilNadu?

Tags: ganesha, resource

Long time ago (20 yrs ago) I used to have a copy of a book called 'Vinayaka Vijayam'. It is a Tamil book, which I believe is from LIFCO publications. The book had wonderful, unknown and elaborate background behind Ganesh ji's worship and mythology associated with his birth/his legend. I want to read this book again. Can I find it anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

The book is available for purchase on website of LIFCO books.

### [Vinayaga Vijayam](http://www.lifcobooks.com/product/vinayaga-vijayam/).

[image: Screenshot of Vinayaga Vijayam book cover from website]

I hope this is the one you are looking for.